# Glassfish incremental deployment failes when including Selenium

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, selenium, glassfish, xerces

I have a Java EE project which is meant to run on **Glassfish 4.1**. I want to use **Selenium** to collect information from some web pages, i.e. I need to include Selenium in the deployment (not just for tests).

I am using **Eclipse IDE** and have previously utilized the incremental deployment function in Eclipse to automatically deploy all saved changes to the project. But **when I included (with Maven) the dependencies for Selenium incremental deployment stopped working**. The project can still be deployed to Glassfish but I have to restart Glassfish between every change. I get the following error in Eclipse:

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

*org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl* is included with Selenium as a transitive dependency (xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0).

Here are my Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
  <version>2.44.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I hope there is a solution to this but after reading Jens Schauder's response in [Dealing with "Xerces hell" in Java/Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven) I'm afraid there might not be. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I currently can't reproduce the issue with a simple project, did you make sure that you don't have any other dependencies which are importing another version of `xercesImpl`?

You can try to place the `xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar` and the transitive dependency `xml-apis-1.4.01.jar` in the `lib` folder of your Glassfish domain and exclude it from your dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
  <version>2.44.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**See also:**

- [org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057733/org-apache-xerces-impl-dv-dvfactoryexception-dtd-factory-class-org-apache-xerce)
- [Xerces error: org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730103/xerces-error-org-apache-xerces-impl-dv-dtd-dtddvfactoryimpl)